# How to access and display database (MongoDB) information in the view (HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express, database

I have a database on mlab.com that I can successfully post to using this code in my controller:

```
app.post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  var newEvent = req.body;
  db.collection('events').insertOne(newEvent, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      error(res, "Failed to create new event.");
    } else {
      res.sendFile('views/dashboard.html', { root: '.' });
    }
  });
});
```

At the localhost:8080/dashboard URL, I have a form where a user can enter in event data.

Now my question is, how do I get that data to be able to display it in the HTML? For example, displaying a list of all the events entered at that same /dashboard URL but in a different location on the page. I believe I need to do something along these lines:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
  db.collection('events').findOne( {
    eventName : req.body.eventName
  }, function(err, doc) {
    // ????
  });
});
```

But then how do I display the data I got back in the HTML view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I've been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Comment: Can you post the code of your html view file from which you call the /dashboard route?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1) Use a templating system like ejs or jade and render the page. For example if you are passing variables to a dashboard.ejs file located in views/pages folder, you call it like

```
res.render('views/pages/dashboard', {
            feild1: value1,
            feild2: value2
        });
```

Then print it in dashboard.ejs using a code like

```
<div><%= feild1 %></div>
<div><%= feild2 %></div>
```

Lots of documentation is available in the net for both the options

2) Send data as json and use some javascript code or javascript based front end framework to render them. If you are good in front end javascript coding, you can go for this approach

```
var data = { "feild1" : doc.xxx, "feild2" : doc.yyyy };
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The json can be accessed using an ajax call from client side (you can use jquery for that)

```
$.getJSON('/dashboard', function(obj) {
    alert(obj.feild1);
    alert(obj.feild2);
});
```

Comment: I believe the data is being sent as a json object and I'm able to access that using req.body.eventName for example, but I'm unsure how to access that data in the HTML file

Comment: I did not see any req.send() in your code. Can you post tthe full code

Comment: Currently you are querying only, but not sending back any data as per your code